# Jump Break with ng-bind-html?

Tags: html, angularjs, page-break, ng-bind-html

I have an `array` of `objects` that contain an `html` content `string`. Each `string` contains a `<br>` to act as a jump break. Eg. a blog post that has an intro summary before the jump break, to reduce the amount of space on a web page.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in blog">
    <div ng-bind-html="post.content"></div>
</div>
```

That's a basic example of my code. Is there a way to hide the text after the `<br>` with an angular `ng-` without a complicated javascript filter? I imagine I could probably write CSS to handle this, but I'd like to keep the solution within the HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i would use `.split('<br>')[0]` which will take text before

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="post in blog">
    <div ng-bind-html="post.content.split('<br />')[0]"></div>
</div>
```

You could move this code to your controller to make html code looks readable.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="post in blog">
    <div ng-bind-html="showFirstBr(post.content)"></div>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.showFirstBr = function(content){
    return content.split('<br />')[0]
};
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/o7eY8bnyhbOjEOKvQwYC?p=preview)

Comment: The html comes from blogger using an API call. I can't change the `<br>` to `\n`, unfortunately.

Comment: It didn't seem to do anything. I'm not sure if you can call the split function within an angular expression.

Comment: @AnthonyJ.Barrera yes you can call it from the angular expression..but better would be move it to controller and make this from there..

Comment: You're right, the split does work, I tested it with `[1]` and everything disappeared. It's not matching the `<br>` for some reason.

Comment: @AnthonyJ.Barrera I assumed that your html could contain `<br>` tag..could you please paste the here which you are receiving..

Comment: It was appearing differently after being rendered than when it was an object. In the object it was `<br />` so now it works. Thank you for you solution.

Comment: @AnthonyJ.Barrera Glad to help you..Thanks :)